# How to solve Linear programs of the form Maximize v

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I face difficulties in solving LPs in the form

```
Maximize v
subject to:
a11x1+a12x2<=v
...........<=v
```

The v is the variable I want to maximize. Should I treat this as a variable?
If I move the v to the left size of the constrains I have zeros in the tableau and I can not perform pivot moves because the ratio remains always zero.
Is there a methodology to cope with such Lps?

Comment: Yes you must consider $v$ as a variable. But how are you applying Simplex iterations? You need to be careful because your problem is not in standard form: you do not have bound constraints $(x,v) \geq 0$ (unless you omitted to specify them).

Comment: Why it is not in standard form ? Dont I have constrains x1+x2+...-v<=0? The 0 means that it is not in standard form? I am really stuck on that !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just add $v$ to your variables, as you suggested. Then you'll get this form of linear program:

$$\max {\bf a}^T{\bf x},\quad {\bf A}{\bf x}\le {\bf 0}$$

where ${\bf x}^T=[x_1,\ldots x_n,v]$ is your vector of unknowns, and
${\bf a}^T=[0,\ldots,0,1]$. All elements of the last column of matrix $\bf A$ are $-1$ (because you've moved $v$ to the left side of the inequalities).

Comment: Thank you for your response. The last column will be -1 I agree with that but every inequality will have the form something<=0 am I right on that? Ok of course you have written it. But I have problem when the system is less equal to 0 because then in simplex what ever move I perform the ratio in the tableau will be zero... so never increasing the objective.

Comment: I used to have LPs of exactly the same form, but they were huge, so I solved them using some software, and it worked! I know they can be solved but I have no idea how to solve them by hand, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your solution by the way!I also solve them using Maple.